# How to use ‘apply’ with function that returns wrong dimensions (R)

Tags: r, anonymous-function

I have a general purpose function that I use with various scripts that returns a vector of dimension greater than one. But, I want to use this function with ‘apply’ and use only one of the results in the returned vector. Is there a way to do this without rewriting the called function??

Here is a toy example. I define function ‘dummy’ that accepts a vector and returns the minimum and maximum value in a 2-vector. I want to call it to operate on a matrix column-by-column using ‘apply’ but I am only interested in the min answer (‘b’ in the example below). Is there a way to do that?

```
dummy <- function(x)
{
  a <- max(x)
  b <- min(x)
  return(c(a,b))
}
z <- matrix(c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), nrow = 3)
apply(z, 2, dummy)
```

This gives the answer 5,5, which is nonsense. Is there a way to pass dummy as the anonymous function so that I only use the second element of the returned vector for each column of z?

Comment: If I run your code I get a matrix back with per column the min and max of the columns.  4 and 2, 7 and 5, 10 and 8

Comment: Works with me. Your code is great. If you want just the second value, `apply(z, 2, min)` is more than enough, no need for an anonymous function.

Comment: Guess I picked a poor example. My real function is much more complex than my toy example. I want the result of second returned argument from dummy, ignoring the fact that in my toy example I could just say apply(z,2,min).

Comment: I need to structure an anonymous function that has a function of a function, the first function calling the second and handing back only the selected returned value, in this case, b. I don’t know how to do that.

Comment: As in `apply(z, 2, function(x){y <- dummy(x); y <- log(y[2]); y})`? This anonymous function calls a function, `dummy`, then does something with one of the returned values (it computes the logarithm) and returns the result of that something.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I also see that apply(z, 2, dummy) in my original example is returning a 2X3 matrix, the first row a vector of the max values and the second row a vector of the min values. I could also just say apply(z, 2, dummy)[2, ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can get some inspiration from the following example.
The anonymous function uses hard-coded function `dummy` and another function, the argument `fun` set equal to `log`.

```
dummy <- function(x){
  a <- max(x)
  b <- min(x)
  c(a, b)
}

z <- matrix(c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), nrow = 3)
apply(z, 2, dummy)

apply(z, 2, function(x, fun){
    y <- dummy(x)
    y <- fun(y[2])
    y
}, fun = log)
#[1] 0.6931472 1.6094379 2.0794415
```

Another possibility would be to have `itworks` need two arguments, the vector `x` and a function chosen on a case by case basis.

```
itworks <- function(x, fun){
  qq <- quantile(x)
  fun(qq[2])
}

apply(z, 2, itworks, fun = sin)
#[1]  0.5984721 -0.7055403  0.7984871
```

The point here is that the arguments a function takes can be anything, including other functions. `apply` has 3 mandatory arguments, `X`, `MARGIN` and `FUN`, plus the `dots` argument. In the dots argument you can pass whatever you want as long as `FUN` accepts it.